# Eventlistener - mouseleave - dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, dropdown, event-listener

Trying to figure out how to use the mouseleave event when the mouse leaves all the elements in a dropdown menu.  It currently only works when the mouse leaves the submenu, but not the About element as well as the submenu elements.  Driving me crazy and been trying to figure it out for HOURS.

```
<ul class="navigation__list-menu">
        <li class="navigation__list-menu-about">
          <a href="/about" class="now">About</a>
        </li>
        <ul id="nav" class="navigation__list-menu-about-options now">
          <li><a href="/bio">my bio</a></li>
          <li><a href="/cv">curriculum vitae</a></li>
        </ul>

<script>
const navOptions = document.querySelector(".navigation__list-menu-about");

const navOptionMenu = document.querySelector(
  ".navigation__list-menu-about-options"
);


navOptions.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  navOptionMenu.classList.add("active");
});

navOptions.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
  navOptionMenu.classList.remove("active");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is one list intended to be nested in the other? If so, the inner list must be inside a parent `<li>` because [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) can only hold "[z]ero or more <li>, <script> and <template> elements," meaning that it can't have another `<ul>` as a direct child. Also, may we see the relevant CSS? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Got it, I was wondering if nesting a<ul> and <li> element inside an <li> would be an issue.  I will definitely try to give better context for next time.  I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: Have you missed some word in this statement?. "Trying to figure out how to use the mouseleave event when the mouse leaves all the elements in a dropdown menu." What you want when mouse leave happen?

Comment: From this line it seems that you are saying the code you have shared is working for sub menu items as expected   "It currently only works when the mouse leaves the submenu, but not the About.." Based on this I put my answer. If you will add more elaboration I will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are only manipulating the sub items. You need to add/remove the class to the about item too. Please have a look at the code snippet below

```js
const navOptions = document.querySelector(".navigation__list-menu-about");

const navOptionMenu = document.querySelector(
  ".navigation__list-menu-about-options"
);


navOptions.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  navOptions.classList.add("active");
});

navOptions.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
  navOptions.classList.remove("active");
});

navOptionMenu.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  navOptionMenu.classList.add("active");
});

navOptionMenu.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
  navOptionMenu.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```html
<style>
  .active,
  .active a {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<ul class="navigation__list-menu">
  <li class="navigation__list-menu-about">
    <a href="/about" class="now">About</a>
  </li>
  <ul id="nav" class="navigation__list-menu-about-options now">
    <li><a href="/bio">my bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cv">curriculum vitae</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this still doesn't work.  It takes off the active class when the mouse leaves the "about" or "navOptions" element.  Thus not allowing me to select the sub list.

Answer (score 0):

Event bubbling will always pass the event from child tag to parent tag unless there is a JavaScript code to abort it.

Which means by listening to the parent `navigation__list-menu` you can get all events from its child's too. based of the `event.target` you can understand where event came from.

If you can't get the event at parent then there might be:

- Some code that does `event.stopPropogation()` from child node.
- your HTML code have Structural issues